# MKMapView - Does it cache Pins?

Tags: ios, caching, mkmapview

I had something interesting happen and now I can't replicate it.

I have a number of custom pins based on different location types. I changed the size of the pin graphics.

When I relaunched the app, some of the pins were the showing at the old size.

What's strange is that I deleted the app. Only when I rebooted the phone did the pins show at the right size.

Beyond tiles, is anything else cached in MKMapView?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Xcode sometimes doesn't update changed resource files when it updates the app on your device or in the simulator. Deleting the previous version of the solves the problem. What you're seeing surely doesn't have anything to do with MKMapView -- other people have reported the same kinds of issues with other resources.